# Curve Modifier doesn't work at all in some curves Not even deformation of shapes

Tags: modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

I've been working on a project that is basically just a lot of bezier curves that I have to put some complex shapes on, I use the common Array with Follow Curve and then the Curve Modifier, it works wonderfully but there are some curves that for some reason seem to not work **at all.**

They don't even deform the shape on any axis, it just sits there doing nothing. Why is this? I checked all the settings in the curve tab but everything looks the same as the ones that work!

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B29CctXANrKxS05MaFhuM3RSSW8/view?usp=sharing)

[Example of 2 curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nerwu.jpg)

Edit: Updated file, as you start up you can see 2 curves, one that works with the modifiers and one that doesn't.

Comment: Just from your file I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Can you show images that exemplify which ones are working and which aren't?

Comment: Okay; Look at these pictures: http://imgur.com/a/TwuuH

1st) I moved to 2 curves from the main layer to make it easier, one is already covered with the model, other isnt.

2nd) Here's the curve that works, with the model selected, as you can see it has the 2 modifiers linked to the curve inside, and it is following it as intented

3rd) Here's the model for the other curve, as you can see even with all the modifiers it stays the same, not being affected at all by the curve. Changing axis doesn't work. The properties of the 2 curves are the same. This is the problem. I'll update the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think curve called `Problem Curve` does really has problems. I couldn't reproduce this behaviour which is the fact that neither *Fit Curve* option of **Array** modifier doesn't work nor mesh can't be curved with it. Re-adding modifiers also won't change that.

[image: problem curve not working]

The possible solutions are:

- model another curve and use it instead of this one;
- refresh several settings of **Array** modifier and clean existing curve.

If using the second solution, the steps are:

1. With `Problem Curve_Model` selected in settings of **Array** modifier set *Fit Length*, set some random value, then return option to *Fit Curve*.
2. In order to finish solution you should clean the curve; it has too many vertices which is overkill in this case (and for some reason it allows modifiers to work further on mesh object).
   Select curve, in Edit mode select all, make any vertex active and in 3D View header choose *Select* > *Checker Deselect* operator. When vertices are selected one by one, delete them via <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*. The mesh will become curved. Make sure to recalculate normals on the mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Edit mode with all selected).

   [image: curved mesh]